# how to export SQL query to excel with column names

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

The code below will accept an sql file and export the data to excel using xlsxwriter but I cannot seem to get it to export with the column names as well (header). I can get it to display the column names onto the screen though, but cannot get it to add it as the first row to the excel file.

I did notice that if I change to using DictCursor instead of SSCursor, the excel file will instead be filled with just the column names repeated many times.

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('ISO-8859-1')

sql_file = sys.argv[1]
target_file = sys.argv[2]
target_sheet = sys.argv[3]

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # Not named on 2.6
    access = 'wb'
    kwargs = {}
else:
    access = 'wt'
    kwargs = {'newline':''}

workbook = Workbook(target_file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(target_sheet)

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="username",
                     passwd="password",
                     db="database"
                     , compress=1
                     )

with open(sql_file, 'r') as sql_script:
    sql_string = sql_script.read()


cur = conn.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
#print sql_string
cur.execute(sql_string)
results = cur.fetchall()

print ([i[0] for i in cur.description])

cur.close()
conn.close()

for r, row in enumerate(results):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write(r, c, col)

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the column names and write them in the first row, then proceed with writing the row values.

```
cols = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
for c, col in enumerate(cols):
    worksheet.write(0, c, col)
```

For writing the row values:

```
for r, row in enumerate(results):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write(r+1, c, col)
```